# Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be sequences . if ... $\lim _{n\to \infty } |a_n - b_n| = 1$ prove that $b_n$ is Convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ two  sequences .

if $a_n$ is Convergent

and  $\lim _{n\to \infty } |a_n - b_n| = 1$

> prove that $b_n$ is also Convergent

I know that it is not true but I need to find example I think

$a_n=\frac{1-n}{n}$

$b_n = \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$

Is this correct and if not how to prove it ?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Try $a_n=0$ and $b_n=(-1)^n$.